# SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) - cannot connect because of gap between versions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a similar problem. I am trying to migrate an Access database to a SQL Server 2012 with the SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (SSMA) v8.24. So I began by creating a project a carefully specifying a migration to a SQL Server 2012. But when i try to conect to SQL Server, I get the following error :

> You cannot connect to an older version (SQL Server 2008) of target SQL Server from a higher version SSMA project (Project type = SQL Server 2012). Try creating another SSMA project of project type which matches the version of target SQL Server you are connecting to OR connect to a target SQL Server equal to SQL Server 2012.

I don't understand what is wrong since the version of the SQL server is supposed to be the same as the version specified for the migration project.

Comment: Why are you trying to migrate to sql server 2012? This is migrating from one unsupported version to another.

Comment: It seems that "try to conect to SQL Server" means you are using a version of sql server that is earlier than 2012. Is that correct?

Comment: @SMor yes, that's what I understand too, however I have checked and I am using sql server 2012 even though the SSMA seems to detect an older version